# what is the difference between Redirect:to() and Redirect::route()?

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-4

I am learning laravel 4.

The code of my route file:

```
Route::post('user/admin', 'UserController@admin');
Route::get('user/login', 'UserController@login');
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
});
```

The code of my controller:

```
public function admin() {
    $msg = Usr::get_data();

    if ($msg == "pass") {
        return View::make('user.admin');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('user/login');
    }
}
```

There is no problem when i use Redirect::to, but if i change to Redirect::route, it said route [user/login] is not defined. But I already defined it in the routes.php. Why Redirect::() does not work, and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Redirect::route` is for a [named route](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) whereas `Redirect::to` is for any internal redirect. None of the routes you've added are named, so you cannot use `Redirect::route` to refer to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect::to retrurns a redirect with the flash data
```

An example from the documentation

```
return Redirect::to('user/login')->with('message', 'Login Failed');
```

While `Redirect::route` Returnns A Redirect To A Named Route.

```
return Redirect::route('profile', array(1));
```

Check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/responses).It will make you  understand better.

Edit:

```
Redirect::route() can redirect with a flash data too.
```

Comment: Redirect::route can also redirect with flash data

Comment: i didnt told it cant ..yes it can redirect with the flash data..thats why i gave the documentation like for more info

Comment: improve your answer.. it sound ambiguous

Comment: i have improved ...i think its what the op wanted

Comment: i have taken off the downvote but still it is confusing 'Redirect::to retrurns a redirect with the flash data'